# javascript function inside href attribute

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, ckeditor, href

I am trying to invoke a javascript function inside a "href" attribute of an anchor tag but i receive an error when i try to do so.

The HTML:

```
 <a href="javascript:void('Cut')"</a>
```

The console is showing the following error:

```
APPHOST9602: 'javascript:' is an invalid attribute value and will be ignored.  Don’t use 'javascript:' URIs in the local context.
```

This error occurs in a **windows** cordova webapp.

**Important note**: i cannot change or remove the href attribute since it gets added by an external library(CKEditor).

Comment: how come you need it inside a href ?

Comment: Because this piece of code is from an external library(CKeditor). Someone else added it.

Comment: talk about a quick reply

Answer (score 2):

You can not call a function like this

```
 <a href="javascript:void('Cut')"></a>
```

You have to call the function in something like "JavaScript events"

```
<a href="#" onclick="void('Cut');"></a>
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but the problem is that this piece of HTML is being added dynamically by an external library(CKeditor). Any idea how to get around this issue ?

Comment: sorry never used CKeditor but i found this ..http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/element.setAttribute-href-anything-wont-apply hope its helpful

Comment: I've tried that fix but the problem is that the tag is removed to late. I'll probably have to change the source code of the library. Nevertheless thanks for your help

Comment: if you used jquery , b4 you use document. ready() remove the tag and then under document. ready write the onclick event

Answer (score 1):

how about `<a href="#" onclick="foo"></a>`

```
function foo(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   // do something more
}
```

Comment: Same as with Menaka's post, i can't change the href attribute since its being added dynamically by an external library.

Comment: can you add onclick? because then you can override the click anyway.